# chain unlimited number of asynchronous calls in angularjs to IndexedDB

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise, indexeddb

I'm using **IndexedDB** on an angular project. Since IndexedDB is asynchronous, I'm having some troubles chaining an unlimited number of async calls to the database (this sounds pretty bad, I know :)).

My database schema contains a single `tasks` store, like this:

```
var taskStore = db.createObjectStore('task', {
   keyPath: 'id'
});
```

Given an array of task ids, I need to retrieve all the tasks that correspond to those ids. I have a factory 'db' service that deals with the data layer, and I'm using promises to make the async calls:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).factory(db, function()){
    return {
        findTaskById: function(taskid){ //retrieves in a promise a single task, by its id
            //...async code, removed for brevity
        }
    };
});
```

Since IndexedDB won't let me query with an 'OR' clause, I'm planning of chaining an indefinite number of calls to the `findTaskById` method, one for each needed task id.

Example: To retrieve four tasks, my code would be:

```
var taskIds = [100,101,102,103];
var results = [];
var deferred = $q.defer();
db.findTaskById(taskIds[0])
    .then(function(task){ 
        results.push(task); 
        return db.findTaskById(taskIds[1])
            .then(function(task2){ 
                results.push(task); 
                   return db.findTaskById(taskIds[2])
                       .then( ... etc
//later in the code, return everything in a single promise
deferred.resolve(results);
```

The above code is awful and not working without knowing first the number of tasks ids .

My questions are:

**Question 1**
How can I chain multiple, unlimited asynchronous calls and return a single promise containing all the results?

<s>**Question 2**
How to efficiently query indexedDB with an OR clause on the `keyPath` field.</s> Indeed this question deserves it's own SO question

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should really ask two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Array.prototype.map method alongside the $q.all method. This should create promises out of each of your taskIds and fire the callback of $q.all once they are all resolved.

```
var promises = taskIds.map(db.findTaskById);
$q.all(promises).then(function(data) {
    // Do Stuff
});
```